# How can I count instances of a value in multiple CSV files using PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I have a directory of ever-changing CSV files that I wish to read and count the number of times a word appears in a certain "column." I'm using the following code to do it successfully with a single file:

```
$file = 'Some\Random\Directory\myfile.txt');

$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');

$tag = array();

while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    if (isset($tag[$col[2]])) {
       $tag[$col[2]]++;
    } else {
       $tag[$col[2]] = 1;
    }
}
fclose($fh);

$foo = ($tag['foo']);
$bar = ($tag['bar']);
echo $foo;
```

But, I have gotten hung up when attempting to parse the entire directory with this code:

```
$files = glob('Some\Random\Directory\*.txt');
foreach($files as $file){
    $fh = fopen($file, 'rb');

    $tag = array();

    while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {

        if (isset($tag[$col[2]])) {
            $tag[$col[2]]++;
        } else {
            $tag[$col[2]] = 1;
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);

    $foo = ($tag['foo']);
    $bar = ($tag['bar']);
    $foo_sum = array_sum($foo);    
}
echo $foo_sum;
```

This code results in nothing being shown on the page. If I remove the `array_sum()` function and place the `echo` inside the loop, all of the instances of `foo` are displayed, but as one number per file. What is keeping me from obtaining the sum of all the `foo`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reset your array every time you loop. Pull it before your loop 
and evaluate it afterwards

```
$tag = array();
$files = ...;
foreach (...) {
...
}

$foo = ($tag['foo']);
$bar = ($tag['bar']);
$foo_sum = array_sum($foo);    
echo $foo_sum;
```

If you just need the count of `foo`s, you can also do

```
echo $tag['foo'];
```

No need for `array_sum()`, since there will be only one `$tag['foo']`.

Answer (score 0):

try `$foo_sum += array_sum($foo);`. You are overwriting the value every time you loop.